# split a string with a plus sign separated in R

Tags: r, string

I wanted to split a string with "+" separated one and used `strsplit` as below but it doesn't work.
Here is the example

```
strsplit("aa + bb + cc", split = "+")
```

It shows character splitted one like this. Why doesn't it work?

```
[1] "a" "a" " " "+" " " "b" "b" " " "+" " " "c" "c"
```

How can I get this?

```
c("aa", "bb","cc")
```

Comment: Try `strsplit("aa + bb + cc", split = "+",fixed=T)`

Comment: Or try `strsplit("aa + bb + cc", split = "\\+")`

Comment: another one: `all.vars(reformulate("aa + bb + cc"))`

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
strsplit("aa + bb + cc", "\\s*\\+\\s*")[[1]]

[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"
```

The `+` symbol is a regex *metacharacter*, and so needs to be escaped.  If you also want to isolate the terms being added, then add optional whitespace on either side of the `+`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this way

```
library(stringr)
str_split("aa + bb + cc","[\\s\\+]+")
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `scan` from `base R`

```
scan(text = "aa + bb + cc", what = "", sep= "+", strip.white = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc"
```